# Array Intersect PHP

Tags: php

I want to intersect array, the result will go to another array.
So I've written:  `$result = array_intersect($arrayone,$arraytwo);`.

If I make `count($result)` it returns a correct value, but if I make `$result[0]` it returns the following notice: `Notice: Undefined offset: 0`.

Comment: I guess the indices are different; Do a var_dump($result) to check.

Comment: use `var_dump($result);` to inspect the variable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the intersection maintains index. do the following

```
$result = array_intersect($arrayone,$arraytwo);
$result = array_values($result);
```

Then you can access with `$result[0];`

Answer (score 4):

That is because `array_intersect` preserves the keys from its first argument. If `$arrayone` did not have a key `0`, `$result` will also not have one.

If you are not interested in the keys of the result then you can simply reindex it with `array_keys($result)` and then access the elements given numeric indexes.

However, do keep in mind that directly referring to items inside an array with numeric indexes is somewhat unusual in PHP; in most cases there are more appropriate ways to handle numerically indexed arrays.